# Hashed passwords for NTLM authentication

Tags: passwords, windows, hash, iis

I understood that Windows users' password hashes can be exported very easily. Right? So my question is:

If I can have the hashes of other user accounts (e.g. local users on my Windows machine), isn't it good enough for me for impersonating other users?

For example, when a user tries to log into some web site using NTLM, only the HASH of the password is used for the challenge process. So if I already have this hash (as it is saved locally and can be exported easily), doesn't it mean that I can fake the challenge process? Why do I need to crack the password if the hash can be good enough for me?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_the_hash

Comment: Ah-yes.  And here we go:  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/168940/what-harm-is-there-in-obtaining-password-hashes-in-a-windows-environment

Answer (score 5):

You are absolutely correct. This is a very well known problem with NTLM authentication and the resulting attack is known as [Pass the Hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_the_hash). There is in fact a very handy tool called [Pass-The-Hash toolkit](http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pass-The-Hash_Toolkit) that makes exploiting this *really* easy.